# custom UITextField in iOS phone book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do I create something like this:

[image]

This is taken from the iOS contacts app. I assume there should be away to re-create it as well.

Comment: so did you try something, to create this so far then please! post the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case You need to take Two element

1) `UILabel` **with text color Blue**
2) `UITextField` **with PlaceHolder text** = **@"Phone"**

And this element add in `cell.contentView` with it's **fram** as you need.

also you need to add Line image in between `UILabel` and `UITextField` and add this image in `cell.contentView`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Take Green Box as one image.
2. Add One UITextField as shown in Red box with Placeholder Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to re-create, just take create custom UITableViewCell with a UILabel,a separator as UIImageView and a UITextField with border style as UITextBorderStyleNone and placeholder with your text.

[image: THis is how it looks]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a grouped UITableView using a UITableViewCell with **UITableViewCellStyleValue2**. More info at [Apple documentation for tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1).